# On OS X the Cisco AnyConnect client works only once

Tags: macos, vpn

I'm running OS X 10.7 and am using the Cisco AnyConnect client for VPN.

It works fine the first time, but if I disconnect then reconnect, the VPN no longer "works", meaning things look fine but I can't actually get to any of the VPN's internal ip addresses, they simply come back as unreachable as if the VPN weren't active at all.

With the old vpn client I used to restart /usr/sbin/racoon to solve this, but with AnyConnect this no longer works.  Also, I'd prefer to avoid OpenConnect because of the tuntap kernel extensions it requires, which have royally messed up my machine in the past.

So my only recourse at this point is to reboot the machine to get AnyConnect working again.  That gets tiresome fast.  Anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Check the routing table after second connect. The problem may be in the service order in the Network settings. Go to "System Preferences" -> "Network". Click on the gear icon below the services list and choose "Set Service Order...". Then drag cisco vpn service to the top.